# JavaScript URL issue with Permalinks enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following JavaScript function to fetch the data using ajax call

```
function findName() {
    var name = "Jhon";
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php",
        data: { name : name },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
    })
}
```

It calls the following php file and works fine.

```
http://127.0.0.1/osclass/oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php
```

But when I enable SEO friendly Permalinks in my CMS current page URL is appended in start of link and I get the following error in Chrome Console.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/osclass/fashion-beauty/oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php?name=Jhon 404 (Not Found)
```

Anybody tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you've provided in the ajax call is document relative. When you changed the server's url generation scheme, you also caused the url pointed at by the ajax call to change.

Adjust the ajax url, changing:

```
url: "oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php",
```

To:

```
url: "/osclass/oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php",
```

Comment: Wouldn't that point to `http://127.0.0.1/oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php`? There is another directory present in there.

Comment: Thanks @Ouroborus, your solution works with a problem for me,
My webapp is going to be installed on many servers, on some servers it will be installed in the root of server and on some servers it will be installed in some folder e.g. OSClass. Can you tell me how to get rid of mentioning folder name e.g. OSClass in the url?

Comment: @Syed I don't think you can on the browser side. On the server side, since it's PHP, there should be a variable somewhere that controls what the site root path is. Using that, it should be possible to dynamically generate the correct paths in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the URL server-relative? Something like this:

```
function findName() {
    var name = "Jhon";
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/osclass/oc-content/themes/bender/ajax-test.php",
        data: { name : name },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
    })
}
```

Comment: So what would this change?

Comment: In the question asked, you can see the two URLs being hit are different, something that can be handled by pointing to a server relative URL. Am I missing something?

Comment: _But when I enable SEO friendly Permalinks in my CMS current page URL_ see this is a CMS project and Permalinks are mostly work for GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted the `php` code. I would mention that any url directly navigated through addressbar of browser causes in the `GET` request and i can see you have a `POST` request in the ajax, so, it can't work.

Workaround would be to use `$_REQUEST` super globals at php end. `$_REQUEST` would work for `$_GET/$_POST` requests.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the question. OP implies that it was working previous to their change to the URL generation scheme.